# Conditional Random Sample in R

Tags: r, random, sampling

I am wondering what the best way to solve this is. Essentially I want to generate 20 samples which add to 100 but also where (x1+x2>20). I am struggling to get something that is fast and efficient. I realise that I could filter out the lines that don't meet this criteria but it isn't efficient if I generate 10,000 rather than 20.

The code is as below:

```
n = 20
x1 = sample(0:100,n,replace = TRUE)
x2 = sample(0:100,n,replace = TRUE)
x3 = sample(0:100,n,replace = TRUE)
index = (x1+x2+x3)>100
G=(x1+x2)>20
while(sum(index)>0&&sum(G)>0){
   x1[index&&G] = sample(0:100,n,replace = TRUE)
   x2[index&&G] = sample(0:100,n,replace = TRUE)
   x3[index&&G] = sample(0:100,n,replace = TRUE)
index =(x1+x2+x3)>100
G=(x1+x2)>20
}
x4=rep(100,n)-x1-x2-x3

df <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The distribution of your `x4` won't be the same as `x1, x2, x3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an unbiased way to pick k numbers in the range 0:n which sum to n. It is based on the [stars and bars encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29):

```
#picks k random numbers in range 0:n which sum to n:

pick <- function(k,n){
  m <- n + k - 1 #number of stars and bars
  bars <- sort(sample(1:m,k-1)) #positions of the bars
  c(bars,m+1)-c(0,bars)-1
}
```

This generates a single example, returning a vector. As @Guillaume Devailly observes in their answer, most of the samples will satisfy the additional constraint on the sum of the first 2 numbers, so you can just filter out those that don't.

Note that if you want 4 numbers in the range 1:100 which sum to 100 you could just use `1 + pick(4,96)`.

To enforce the constraint on the first two numbers:

```
pick.sample <- function(){
  while(TRUE){
    x <- pick(4,100)
    if(sum(x[1:2]) >20) return(x)
  }
}
```

Then

```
df <- data.frame(t(replicate(10000,pick.sample())))
```

will create a 10,000 row dataframe where each row is a sample which satisfies the constraints.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I thought I might be ok once I get some ideas but there are other conditions I want to add. i.e. I might want x[3] <10 or have k=10 so x[9]<10 and x[3]<10 etc. 

These conditions are on single columns rather than 2 columns added. Thoughts?

Comment: Unless the additional constraints are too hard to satisfy by chance, the best thing might be a hit-and-miss approach (similar to the above code handles the constraints on `x1,x2`). The function `pick(n,k)` can generate tens of thousands of samples per second. Even if there is only a 1% chance that a randomly chosen sample will satisfy a given list of constraints, you can still quickly generate a large number of samples which satisfy the constraint. If the constraints become even harder to satisfy, you might need a fundamentally different approach.

Comment: The constraints can be satisfied by chance within a range. I.e. x[1] the pick might be between 0 and 10 rather than 0 and 100, x[2] the pick might be between 0 and 40 rather than 0 and 100, these two combined must be >20 which can easily be met and the sum of x1, x2, x3, x4 = 100. It can be done by sampling but becomes more difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility:
Pick three **breaks** of the sequence `0:100`.
x1, x2, x3 and x4 are then generated in-between those breaks. If `x1 + x2` is smaller than 20, then `x3 + x4` is greater than 20, so we can swap them.

```
generate_four_numbers <- function(from = 0, to = 100) {
    breaks <- sort(sample(seq(from, to), 3 ,replace = TRUE))
    x1 <- breaks[1]
    x2 <- breaks[2] - breaks[1]
    x3 <- breaks[3] - breaks[2]
    x4 <- 100 - breaks[3]

    if (x1 + x2 <= 20) {
        return(data.frame(x1 = x4, x2 = x3, x3 = x2, x4 = x1)
    }

    data.frame(x1, x2, x3, x4)
}

res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:10000, function(x) generate_four_numbers()))

table(rowSums(res)) # all at 100

length(which(res$x1 + res$x2 > 20)) / nrow(res) # 100 % acceptable
```

Comment: This is a good idea (so +1),  but I think that it undersamples solutions which contain a 0. Those correspond to when repeated numbers are chosen in `breaks`. Note that there is only one way that a pair of numbers can both be {10,10} but two ways that they can be e.g. {10,20}: 10 then 20 but also 20 then 10.

Comment: Is there a typo in the above code? I seem to get an error "unexpected }".

Answer (score 0):

To generate one such vector, you could do:

```
# generate x1+x2
x1_plus_x2 <- sample.int(79,1) + 20
# generate x1 and x2 
x1x2 <- rmultinom(1, x1_plus_x2, c(1,1))
# generate x3 and x4
x3x4 <- rmultinom(1, 100-x1_plus_x2, c(1,1))
# generated x1,x2,x3,x4
x <- c(x1x2, x3x4)
```

You can loop to generate `n` samples. You can gain speed by generating the `n` values of `x1+x2` at the beginning:

```
n <- 20
# matrix to store the simulations
x <- matrix(NA_integer_, nrow=n, ncol=4)
# generate all the x1+x2's
x1_plus_x2 <- sample.int(79, n, replace=TRUE) + 20
# loop 
for(j in 1:n){
  # generate x1 and x2 
  x1x2 <- rmultinom(1, x1_plus_x2[j], c(1,1))
  # generate x3 and x4
  x3x4 <- rmultinom(1, 100-x1_plus_x2[j], c(1,1))
  #
  x[j,] <- c(x1x2,x3x4)
}

> rowSums(x)
 [1] 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
```

Comment: Are the samples chosen with uniform probability from the set of all samples which satisfy the constraints? This isn't an explicit requirement of OP but would make any conclusions suspect if it doesn't hold.

Comment: @JohnColeman No, this is not uniform. This is just a rough possibility. The uniform sampling is a good question.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily brute force this one as follows

```r
#####
# Brute force solution
set.seed(28550697)
n <- 100000L
time. <- proc.time() # to measure time difference
brute <- t(replicate(
  n, {
    repeat {
      xs <- sample.int(101L, 4, replace = TRUE) - 1L
      if(xs[1] + xs[2] > 20L && sum(xs) == 100L)
        break
    }
    xs
  }))
proc.time() - time. # time taken
#R   user  system elapsed 
#R 192.76    0.13  196.74 

# check result
stopifnot(
  all(rowSums(brute) == 100L),
  all(brute %in% 0:100),
  all(brute[, 1] + brute[, 2] > 20L))

# only the first two columns should be able to take values in 0:100
apply(brute, 2, range)
#R      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#R [1,]    0    0    0    0
#R [2,]   99   99   79   79
```

Above I simulate 100,000 pairs in a reasonable time (10 times more than you require). You surely can do better with a more smart approach but here it is clear that the distribution is right.